# How to write a test case for trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have two objects. 
1. Timecard 
2. Period

I have a Trigger in which I am comparing

Timecard month =  Period month and 
Timecard owner company id = Period owner company id

Here *Timecard owner company id*  is not a direct field in Timecard so I am using a List in Unit Test case to get Timecard owner company id. **I am getting an error when I am trying to assign that to Project in Test Case Line 9.**

Trigger

```
  trigger Timecard on pse__Timecard_Header__c (after insert) {

  List<pse__Timecard_Header__c> tc_list = [select Id, pse__End_Date__c, pse__Project__r.pse__Region__r.ffpsai__OwnerCompany__r.Id 
                                             from pse__Timecard_Header__c
                                             where Id IN :Trigger.newMap.KeySet()];

    system.debug('TC_LIST: ' + tc_list);

    Set<Date> tc_setofDate = new Set<Date>();
    Set<Id> tc_setofId = new Set<Id>();


    for (pse__Timecard_Header__c tcdate: tc_list)
        {
            Date aDate = tcdate.pse__End_Date__c.toStartOfMonth();
            tc_setofDate.add(aDate);
            system.debug('SET DATE ' + tc_setofDate);

        }

    for (pse__Timecard_Header__c tcId: tc_list)
        {
            Id ids = tcId.pse__Project__r.pse__Region__r.ffpsai__OwnerCompany__c;
            tc_setofId.add(ids);
            system.debug('SET ID ' + tc_setofId);

        }



    List <c2g__codaPeriod__c> periodDetails = [Select Id, c2g__StartDate__c,c2g__EndDate__c, c2g__OwnerCompany__c
                                                from c2g__codaPeriod__c
                                                where c2g__StartDate__c IN: tc_setofDate
                                                and c2g__OwnerCompany__c IN: tc_setofId];



    system.debug('PERIOD_DETAILS: ' + periodDetails);



    List<pse__Timecard_Header__c> tcUpdate = new List<pse__Timecard_Header__c>();

        for (pse__Timecard_Header__c timecardCompare: tc_list){

        for (c2g__codaPeriod__c periodCompare: periodDetails){


            if ((timecardCompare.pse__End_Date__c.toStartOfMonth() == periodCompare.c2g__StartDate__c) && 
                  (timecardCompare.pse__Project__r.pse__Region__r.ffpsai__OwnerCompany__c == periodCompare.c2g__OwnerCompany__c))
            { 

                    timecardCompare.Period__c = periodCompare.Id;
                    tcUpdate.add(timecardCompare);


            }
       }
    }   

        update tcUpdate;
}
```

Test Case

```
@IsTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class TimecardTest {
static testmethod void insertTimecard(){

    Date someDate = Date.today.toStartOfMonth();

    List<pse__Timecard_Header__c> tc_list = [select Id, pse__Project__r.pse__Region__r.ffpsai__OwnerCompany__r.Id 
                                            from pse__Timecard_Header__c
                                            where Id IN :Trigger.newMap.KeySet()];

    pse__Proj__c testProject = new pse__Proj__c();
    testProject.pse__Region__c = pse__Project__r.pse__Region__r.ffpsai__OwnerCompany__r.Id;

   pse__Timecard_Header__c testTimecard = new pse__Timecard_Header__c();

    testTimecard.pse__End_Date__c = someDate;
    //testTimecard.pse__Resource__c= pmResource.Id;
    testTimecard.pse__Start_Date__c = someDate;
    testTimecard.pse__Project__c = testProject;
    insert testTimecard;



    c2g__codaPeriod__c testPeriod = new c2g__codaPeriod__c();
    testPeriod.c2g__StartDate__c = someDate;
    testPeriod.c2g__OwnerCompany__c = 'compare with timecard company id';

    insert testTimecard;


   Test.startTest();
    insert tc;
   Test.stopTest();

}
}
```

Comment: to start, you will need to create all supporting records as well. I suggest you take some time reading the many resources available on developer.force.com and the many blogs out there. There is a lot of information that can help you. Since this seems to be a write it for me question I am going to vote to close this.

Comment: Your trigger needs to do an update to preserve the changes it makes.

Comment: A `pse__Region__c` is an object in its own right, it's not a FF `c2g__codaCompany__c` which is what your line `testProject.pse__Region__c = pse__Project__r.pse__Region__r.ffpsai__OwnerCompany__r.Id;` is saying.  Also, where are you getting `Trigger.newMap.KeySet()` from in a Test?  It really isn't clear what you're asking though

Comment: @Phil I am new to this so I am not aware what I am doing is completely right or not. I am comparing with some existing examples and trying to create my own test case. So what I understood from your comment is I am trying to assign an object to a field and that's y I am getting error. Also, I can't use `Trigger.newMap.KeySet()` in a test case, right ? So what should be used inplace of **where** ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you dont need to query the pse__Timecard_Header__c records again. They will already be there in Trigger.New
Also you are looping twice over the same list unnecessarily. Simply populate the set of Ids

```
trigger Timecard on pse__Timecard_Header__c (after insert) {

Set<Date> tc_setofDate = new Set<Date>();
Set<Id> tc_setofId = new Set<Id>();

for (pse__Timecard_Header__c tcdate: Trigger.New)
    {
        Date aDate = tcdate.pse__End_Date__c.toStartOfMonth();
        tc_setofDate.add(aDate);
        Id ids = tcId.pse__Project__r.pse__Region__r.ffpsai__OwnerCompany__c;
        tc_setofId.add(ids);

    }
//More stuff here
}
```

Now coming to the Test method, you started out right by inserting a record. But you should also populate the fields that you will be using in the code. In this case `pse__End_Date__c` and `pse__Project__r.pse__Region__r.ffpsai__OwnerCompany__c`
Then you need `c2g__codaPeriod__c` records that satisfy the date given as well as the ownerCompany field.

So your test method should approximately be (Please note that this is just the idea, so change stuff accordingly)

```
public class TimecardTest {
    static testmethod void insertTimecard(){
        ffpsai__OwnerCompany__c ownerCompanyTestRec = new ffpsai__OwnerCompany__c(<all necessary field>)
        insert ownerCompanyTestRec;

        pse__Region__c regionTestRec = new pse__Region__c(ffpsai__OwnerCompany__c = ownerCompanyTestRec.id <other fields>);
        insert regionTestRec;

       pse__Project__c testProject = new pse__Project__c(pse__Region__c = regionTestRec.id <other fields>);
       insert testProject;

     //Similarly insert c2g__codaPeriod__c
     Date someDate = date.newInstance(2014, 12, 12);

     c2g__codaPeriod__c testCodaPeriod = new c2g__codaPeriod__c(c2g__StartDate__c=someDate, c2g__OwnerCompany__c =ownerCompanyTestRec.id );

        pse__Timecard_Header__c tc = new pse__Timecard_Header__c(pse__End_Date__c=someDate, pse__Project__c=testProject.id);


     //now you have everything and you can do an insert
       Test.startTest();
        insert tc;
       Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

Note that you need `@IsTest(SeeAllData=true)` if you plan to use existing data. Try to achieve code coverage without it if possible.

Comment: thank you for the effort u took to answer this but I don't have a clear understanding since I am new to this. I understood u went into the reverse order i.e. for ** pse__Project__c** you assign **Region** which is a child of Project. For Region ** pse__Region__c** you assign **comapny id** which is child but now I don't get what to write there where you have mentioned _all necessary fields_ (1st line). Also, in **pse__Region__c** and **pse__Project__c** you mentioned <other fields> which fields ? Isn't that all what I need ?

Comment: Aslam -- you might want to rewrite your last two sentences -- 1) SeeAllData=true is not best practice as it can lead to deployment failures, especially over time; testmethods should create the necessary records in a test factory and 2) The purpose of testing is two fold - a) to verify that the code does what it is supposed to do so subsequent modifications can be regression tested and b) to achieve SFDC code coverage thresholds. If one does a good job with 2a, code coverage comes naturally and should be in the high 90s